# Jquery/bootstrap modal on top of specific angular 5 component

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `bootstrap` modal in my angular 5 project to open modals. But the way I am doing it right now is making the modal open up on top of the whole screen which I don't want to happen.

here is my angular layout code.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar" data-active-color="white" data-background-color="black" data-image="../assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg">
        <!-- <div class="sidebar" data-color="red" data-image=""> -->
        <sidebar-cmp></sidebar-cmp>
        <div class="sidebar-background" style="background-image: url(assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-panel">
        <navbar-cmp></navbar-cmp>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <div *ngIf="!isMap()">
            <footer-cmp></footer-cmp>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

as you can see there is the `sidebar` component and the `router-outlet`, the modal is present in the `router-outlet`component but it is still displayed on top of the `sidebar`component. both components are shown side by side.

this is how I show the modal in my typescript file :

```
@ViewChild('DetailModal') detailRef: ElementRef;

$(this.detailRef.nativeElement);
$(this.detailRef.nativeElement).modal("show");
```

the modal content is in the definition of the component :

```
<div>
   <!-- The definition of the Component that gets in the router-outlet-->

<div class=" container modal fade" #DetailModal>
    <app-detail-modal [Cert]="DCert"></app-detail-modal>
</div>

</div>
```

how can I make the modal only show on top of the component it is in ?

Comment: It depends on how Bootstrap implements it’s modal. Inspect your page and check is it adding a div to the root of your page and positioning it over everything. If so then you could use CSS to override that backdrop to not cover everything.

Comment: I need the backdrop and the modal itself to be on top of the component, not just the backdrop. So the size of the modal will be changed too. Is there anyway to actually trick the plugins to think that component is all the screen ?

Comment: Try not to think of it as a plug-in, it’s just some css and JS positioning elements in your page. Maybe the way that bootstrap implements it’s modal won’t lend itself to what you want to do. Positioning the modal itself should be easy enough since it is actually inside your component, I think the difficult part will be either making the modal backdrop do what you want OR add styles to prevent their backdrop displaying and add your own that you can position inside your component.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKvQLX here is an example of positioning the modal itself inside a container. next step is to do something about the backdrop.

Comment: ok updated it. it now hides their default backdrop and adds a custom inline backdrop,

Answer (score 0):

You can position the actual modal inside your container with css by making your container position relative, and the modal container position absolute

```
#my-modal-container {
  height:300px;
  width: 600px;
  border: 4px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
}
```

You can then hide the bootstrap overlay and replace it with an inline one.

```
// Hide the default backdrop
.modal-backdrop {
   display: none;
}

// Make another backdrop with styles copied from the jQuery one, and
// place it alongside your modal component
body.modal-open .inline-modal-backdrop {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.5;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1040;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Then you can wrap all this up in an angular component that contains the bs modal container and your new inline backdrop

```
<div class="modal"><ng-content></ng-content></div>
<div class="inline-modal-backdrop"></div>
```

Here is a codepen (without angular)

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rKvQLX